# Prove that the maximum number of knights that can be placed on a chess board NxN such that no knight attacks another is n^2/2

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, chessboard

I need to prove that the maximum number of knights that can be placed on a chess board n x n such that no knight attacks another is $n^2/2$ for even n and $(n^2+1)/2$ for odd numbers.
I guess that all knights should stand on the squares with the same color. 
And for example I can look at chess board 2 x 4 and show that the max number of knights is 4, but how can I use this to prove the whole statement for board n x n?
Thank you!

Comment: By placing knights on all squares of one color, you've shown that you can reach $n^2/2$ or $(n^2 + 1)/2$ (or is it that you have trouble showing that these are the number of squares of a given color on the board?). You haven't proven that you cannot do better.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem to show that I can't place more. Like is it enough to say that every knight on the black square attacks knights only on the white squares? And it's true for all n?

Comment: One idea (I don't know if it works) could be to show that for any $i<n^2/2$ (with $n$ even, $i<(n^2+1)/2$ with $n$ odd), if you have $i$ knights on white squares, then at least $i$ black squares are attacked by those knights, and thus not available to place a new knight on.

Comment: This is the independent knight problem. For the even case, it's quite easy: you divide the squarre in $2\times 4$ rectangles in an obvious way. Then you sort out the different cases, and get that there are at most $4$ independent knights on these rectangles. So each independent knight configuration has $\leq \frac{1}{2}n^2$ knights. For the odd case, it's a little harder. Check J. Watkins' magnificent book, Across the Board. He details a lot more, like the knights tour which you actually use to solve the problem.

Comment: Small edit: to see that ther are at most $4$ independent knights in a $2\times 4$ rectngle, you can just pair the different squarres, by the knights move: you find exactly $4$ pairs. On a $3\times 4$ rectangle you look how far can a knight move and find $4$ disjoint paths, each of $3$ squarres so you pick the $2$ on both ends, so you find at most $6$ knights.